# Decide existence of finite non-abelian group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Decide existence of finite non-abelian group $G$ such that:

- $ ( \exists a,b \in G$) and $\mbox{ord}(a) = \mbox{ord}(b) = 2$
- for above $a,b$: $\mbox{ord}(ab) > 2$

I suppose that correct example may be $D_3$. We can take two symetry $S_{A}$, $S_{B}$ and rotation $R$ about $120^{\circ}$ such that:

$S_{A}(A)=A \\ S_{A}(B)=C\\ S_{A}(C)=B$

$S_{B}(A)=C \\ S_{B}(B)=B \\ S_{B}(C)=A$

$R(A)=B \\ R(B)=C \\ R(C)=A$

where $A,B,C$ are cuspes of equilateral triangle.

Of course we have:

- $S_A \circ S_B = R$
- $\mbox{ord}(S_A) = \mbox{ord}(S_B) = 2$
- $\mbox{ord}(R) = 3 > 2$
- $G$ is non abelian group (it is easy to show) as is finite ($\mbox{ord}(D_3)=6$)

I suppose that my solution is correct but I will grateful if you could confirm it.

Comment: Yes your solution is correct. A slightly simpler way to see this is noting that $D_3=S_3$ and that the product of distinct $2$-cycles (=reflections) is a $3$-cycle (=rotation).

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.  One could also use cycle notation:$$(\operatorname{a}\operatorname{b})(\operatorname{a}\operatorname{c})=(\operatorname{a}\operatorname{b}\operatorname{c})$$ Since $(\operatorname{a}\operatorname{b})$ and $(\operatorname{a}\operatorname{c})$ are transpositions and $(\operatorname{a}\operatorname{b}\operatorname{c})$ is a $3$-cycle, and $S_n$ is nonabelian for $n\geq 3$, we conclude that the proposed groups do exist.